# Define coordinates of 4 corners of image

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I have an image and I want to set two random points in this image two coordinates (Longitude and Latitude) so that I can add it on the map. I am using *Mapbox GL JS* to add image overlay on the map with two coordinates of two points on this image.

My goal is to define coordinates of 4 corner points (top-left, top-right, bottom-left, bottom-right) to put it on the map.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome, Nhan. We need to see some code and, if possible, a link to the working example.

Comment: What are your ideas about how to solve this? Where and how have you searched for answers to your problem already? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to at least try the goal yourself and share your code.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the details of your code, but you can easily get a rectangle, for example, by using an **image source** on the map:

```
"image": {
    "type": "image",
    "url": "https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/radar.gif",
    "coordinates": [
        [-80.425, 46.437],
        [-71.516, 46.437],
        [-71.516, 37.936],
        [-80.425, 37.936]
    ]
}
```

> The `url` value contains the *image location*.
>
> The `coordinates` array contains `[longitude, latitude]` pairs for the image corners listed in clockwise order: *top left, top right, bottom right, bottom left*.

[Source](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#sources-image)

Of course, the URL address and coordinates should be changed to your needs.

I hope it helped.